# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que otros archivos que no están en el directorio sean abiertos por open()?

Tags: python

Necesito que en `open()` se abran distintos archivos que no estén en mi directorio, porque el archivo *program.py* que está en el directorio funciona, pero cuando utilizo otro archivo que no está en el directorio ni en una dirección relacionada no funciona y me genera este error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'program.py'

Dejo aquí el código

```
import sys

lines = []

with open("program.py") as py_file_r:
    lines_code = py_file_r.readlines()
    for line in lines_code:
        if not line.startswith("#"):
            if  line.lstrip():
                lines_list = lines.append(line)

if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    if sys.argv[1] == py_file_r.name:
        print(len(lines))
    elif not sys.argv[1].endswith(".py"):
        sys.exit("Not a Python file")

elif len(sys.argv) < 2:
    sys.exit("Too few command-line arguments")
elif len(sys.argv) > 2:
    sys.exit("Too many command-line arguments")`
```

Comment: Coloca la ruta absoluta

Comment: Se me olvido detallar una cosa y es que es un calificador automático quien me revisa y no puedo colocar la ruta ni acceder al tipo de archivos que utiliza el calificador

Comment: Y como piensas abrir un archivo el cual no conoces su ubicación? Prácticamente tendrías que buscar en todo el sistema. Si solo deseas buscar en la carpeta superior o en un directorio especifico entonces te puede interesar el módulo `pathlib` y su clase `Path`

Answer (score 0):

En el código se aprecia una confusión de conceptos y prácticas que obviaremos para concentrarnos en lo principal: *¿Cómo hacer una rutina que funciones con archivos en cualquier parte?*

La solución es pasar la responsabilidad al usuario, quien deberá proporcionar una ruta (absoluta o relativa) hacia el archivo, invocando el utilitario con

```
python app.py /ruta/al/archivo/a/revisar.py
```

Con esa indicación, el código es:

```
import sys

lines = []
if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    if not sys.argv[1].endswith(".py"):
        sys.exit("Not a Python file")

    with open(sys.argv[1]) as py_file_r:
        for line in py_file_r:
            line = line.strip()
            if not line.startswith("#"):
                lines.append(line)
```

En esta solución se usa el nombre pasado en la llamada para abrir el archivo. Lo recorremos línea a línea (es mala práctica leer el archivo completo con `readlines()`), eliminando los espacios iniciales y finales para luego eliminar los comentarios y salvar el resto.

Al finalizar tendras en `lineas` las líneas filtradas del archivo.